# Отдельный роутинг для /api в SPA

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, маршрутизация, spa

Хочу написать Asp.Net Core SPA.

Стоит стандартная настройка роутинга.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); //ToDo: do it better
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

Но беда в том, что он в том числе и `/api` запросы роутит на главную страницу `index.html` вместо отправки json-ответа. Как и где можно подправить роутинг, чтобы перенаправление было стандартным, за исключением `/api`?

Сами API-контроллеры описываются примерно так:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    //actions here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С такими контроллером и методом

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{   
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Auth([FromBody] TokenRequest tokenRequest)
    {
        var token = await GetToken(tokenRequest.Login, tokenReques
```

Адрес метода будет выглядеть вот так `api/account/auth`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80388/discussion-on-answer-by-tym32167----api--spa).